# Failed to change matplotlib default font

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, fonts

I tried to change the font of matplotlib on my Mac,and here are some steps i have followed:

1.Downloaded the font(SimHei), moved it to matplotlib's folder

2.Changed the matplotlibrc config

**font.family         : sans-serif**

**font.sans-serif      : SimHei, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif**

But as you can see,it didn't work. Still shows messy code when i use it,have i missed any modifications？
Here are exception and result

serWarning: findfont: Font family ['sans-serif']not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7FR2.jpg)

Comment: that is because you are using Chinese. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561009/how-do-you-i-use-mandarin-characters-in-matplotlib) for a solution.

Comment: Yes.i succeed through specifying the file path.but maybe it's not a perfect way.thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by `perfect`? Define it, then I will be able to give further answers.

Comment: Never mind.I just solved it.After modifying all the configurations.i should reload it, for instance:                                                                                
  from matplotlib.font_manager import _rebuild
   _rebuild()    #and the default font is [SimHei]

Comment: See [here](https://jdhao.github.io/2017/05/13/guide-on-how-to-use-chinese-with-matplotlib/) for a more complete discussion on how to use Chinese with matplotlib.